# How to JOIN the same table with itself using ORDER BY RAND()?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I want to get random combinations of `id` of a table with itself.

```
SELECT id FROM t1
SELECT id as id2 FROM t1 ORDER BY RAND()
SELECT id as id3 FROM t1 ORDER BY RAND()
```

How can I `JOIN` these queries to get

```
SELECT id,id2,id3

1    random_id    random_id
2    random_id    random_id
3    random_id    random_id
4    random_id    random_id
5    random_id    random_id
```

In other words, what can be the point of `JOIN`ing to simply place these three `SELECT`s side by side.

It is beneficial to create a unique combination, but with the above query `ORDER BY RAND()` can repeat the same `id` to `id2` and `id3`. The former case is ideal, but the latter sufficiently works for me.

Comment: What about the id1 and id2? Will they be unique in each column?

Comment: What do you mean by "random"?  Can the ids repeat the the columns?  Or do you want a random permutation?

Comment: @forpas not necessarily unique because we have created the list by RAND(), and the same id can appear in `id2` and `id3`. Of course, it would be beneficial to have a unique set, but it still works for me if it is just a random value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the question to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` might work here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())) rn2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()+1)) rn3
    FROM t1
)

SELECT
    t1.id,
    t2.id AS id2,
    t3.id AS id3
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.rn1 = t2.rn2
INNER JOIN cte t3
    ON t1.rn1 = t3.rn3;
```

The demo below was from a sample table containing the `id` values from 1 to 10 inclusive.

[image: screen capture from demo]

### Demo

Comment: Is there a reason you are seeding `rand()` with the unix timestamp?

Comment: unfortunately, I still use MySQL 5.7, but it is a good approach for the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want random, then repeats are allowed.  That suggests:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.id
        from t t2
        order by rand()
        limit 1
       ) as id2,
       (select t3.id
        from t t3
        order by rand()
        limit 1
       ) as id3
from t;
```

If you want permutations in older versions of MySQL, then variables are handy:

```
select t.id, t1.id, t2.id
from (select t.id, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) t join
     (select t.id, (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as seqnum
      from (select t.* from t order by rand()) t cross join
           (select @rn1 := 0) params
     ) t1
     using (seqnum) join
     (select t.id, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as seqnum
      from (select t.* from t order by rand()) t cross join
           (select @rn2 := 0) params
     ) t2 
     using (seqnum);
```

In MySQL 8+, Tim's answer is the best approach.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e595f8466eea31e9e8e71a8a8f8777e7) is a db<>fiddle

Comment: It was my first attempt, but it is very expensive, as the sub-queries should be repeated for each row.

Comment: By the way, as a step towards (not complete) a unique combination, we can add `WHERE t2.id<>t.id` to the first approach.

Comment: @Googlebot . . . The first can be adapted so the ids don't repeat.  Permutations with no duplicates are quite a bit trickier.

Answer (score 1):

For this sample data of sequential ids from *1* to *n*, this query that uses string functions will work and will return in the columns `id2` and `id3` all if the ids once:

```
select t1.id, 
  find_in_set(t1.id, t2.ids2) id2, 
  find_in_set(t1.id, t3.ids3) id3
from tablename t1 
cross join (
  select group_concat(id order by rand()) ids2
  from tablename
) t2
cross join (
  select group_concat(id order by rand()) ids3
  from tablename
) t3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4dBqjSuYPsBkWBWgyRCdwh/0).
Results (like):

```
| id  | id2 | id3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 5   | 4   |
| 2   | 2   | 5   |
| 3   | 1   | 2   |
| 4   | 4   | 3   |
| 5   | 3   | 1   |
```